# msiexec command line to install a software for all users in registry instead of only admin?

Tags: windows, command, windows-installer

Im using following command to install the setup kit on the user's machine using admin account but it seems to be installing for just admin account rather than other's user accounts.

Following is the command that I use.

msiexec /m "Test(Outlook 2016).msi"

How can I change the command so that it will install for all users?

msiexec /m "Test(Outlook 2016).msi"

Comment: What are your exact requirements? Is this an Outlook addin? How many files? What kind of registration do you do?

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like this

`msiexec /i <PATH> ALLUSERS=1 /qn`